# How to display the entity ID next to the title of an ECK entity

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I have an entity template that starts like this:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>">
<h1><?php print $title; ?></h1>
</div>
```

But now I want to display the entity ID and the UUID next to the title.
`<?php print $entity_id; ?>` or `<?php print $entity_id; ?>` display nothing.

Do I need to preprocess something?

Answer (score 0):

$title is an available variable in that entity template. So, yes if you need to pass entity ID and UUID then you will have to pass them via preprocess hook.

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate on that..i'm in the learning phase ;-)

Comment: can you try $entity->id to print the entity id?

Comment: printing $entity->id gives no output

Comment: can you try $entity->entity_id or $entity->eid

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't display like that, firstly you would need to get the entity id then only you can print it after title.
Now if it is a template of node then you can either just get the argument from the url e.g $node_id = arg(1); this will give you the node id and you can print this.

```
<?php print $node_id . ' ' . $title; ?>
```

If it is some other entity then definitely in the url you will be getting some id of the entity.

Another way is that you can write hook_preprocess_page(&$variables) function where in $variables array you can set the value of the entity id e.g $variable['my_entity_id'] = ______  and in your template you can just print $my_entity_id . ' ' . $title;